# Project dependencies not loading in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, build, devexpress, coderush, build-dependencies

I'm not sure if this is a add-on/extension issue but I'm having a heck of a time with Visual Studio 2012 on two computers.  I believe it is DevExpress CodeRush causing the problems as it seems to work fine when I uninstall it but I'm not 100% sure.

I startup VS 2012, answer YES to the Get Latest from TFS 2012 and the solution right-click the solution node in the Solution Explorer and choose Project Dependencies... - it shows nothing checked.  Of course the build will fail.  I close and restart VS 2012 and then it shows.  I typically do this through the course of the DevExpress option to clear the solution cache which causes the solution to reload.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what may cause the project dependencies to get lost yet after a restart they are fine again?  Is there something I need to delete and rebuild to try and resolve this?

Comment: I turned off the Get Latest option in VS 2012's Source Control settings and so far so good.  My guess is that dialog to get latest may be interfering with the solution initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix (so it seems) is to not check the option in VS source control settings to do a Get Latest when opening the solution.  It seems to prevent the solution from initializing properly.  I will consider reporting this to Microsoft Connect.

Answer (score 0):

As I know CodeRush does not change anything in the Project Dependencies dialog. However you can write to DevExpress Support Center (http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center) for a more detailed answer and research.
I also recommend you include a project and a video that illustrates the problem (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue. However got fixed after deleting .suo file from solution folder